# How do i include data from a joined table that doesnt meet the WHERE condition as a null value(SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have 2 tables employees and Medical leave, which are related by the Employee ID, and basically the Medical leave table will have multiple data of a single employee who takes multiple leaves, I want to filter out the data by the month of the medical leave, and include the employees whose medical leave doesnt occur on the filtered month as a null value.

```
       EMPLOYEES                  MEDICAL
    |employee|ID|             |ID|DateOfLeave|
         A     1                1   2019/1/3
         B     2                1   2019/4/15
         C     3                2   2019/5/16
         D     4
```

The sql statement i came up with filters the specific month of the leave and counts the number of times they took a leave on that month such as January, it also includes employees who doesnt have any leave as a '0', however the employees who have medical leaves which doesnt occur on January doesnt show up in the result set at all, how can i show them to have 0 medical leaves in the month of january?

```
select employees.employee, employees.ID,
 count(medical.DateOfLeave) as NumberOfLeaves
from employees
left outer join medical on employees.ID = medical.ID
where (MONTH(DateOfLeave) = 1) or (medical.DateOfLeave is null)
group by employees.employee,employees.ID
```

```
           RESULT SET
    |Employee|ID|NumberOfLeaves|
        A      1      1
        C      3      0   
        D      4      0
```

As you can see B disappears,but i want it to show in the result set as a '0' like employee C and D

I know its because employee B's medical data doesnt meet the condition of the where clause, but how do i write a statement that includes employees who have medical leaves which doesnt occur on january in the result set as a 0??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is only showing results for employees that have leave in January or do not have leave at all.

Instead, you only want to join to records in your medical table if there are records for the specified month, then you'll group your results and get the counts from there.

In order to do this, you need to change the condition for your join to include your Month filter.

Here's a working example using table variables

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (ID INT, Employee CHAR(1))
DECLARE @Medical TABLE (ID INT, DateOfLeave DATE)

INSERT INTO @Employees
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'), (4, 'D')

INSERT INTO @Medical 
VALUES (1, '2019-01-03'), (1, '2019-04-15'), (2, '2019-05-16')

SELECT          e.employee, 
                e.ID,
                count(m.DateOfLeave) AS NumberOfLeaves
FROM            @Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Medical m ON   e.ID = m.ID AND MONTH(DateOfLeave) = 1
GROUP BY        e.employee,e.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

left outer join will first join the table and then filter. in your case B is left out in the join itself so thats why the filter is not working. you can try this

```
select employees.employee, employees.ID,
 nvl(count(medical.DateOfLeave),0) as NumberOfLeaves
from employees
left outer join (select * from medical 
where (MONTH(DateOfLeave) = 1)) 
on employees.ID = medical.ID
group by employees.employee,employees.ID
```

or you can also try this

```
   select e.id, employee, count(dateofleave)
from employee e, medical m
where e.id = m.id
and month(m.DateOfLeave) = 1
group by e.id, employee
UNION ALL
select id, employee, 0
from employee e
where not exists(select 1 from medical m
where e.id = m.id
and month(m.DateOfLeave) = 1
```